# Obscure a div with an image in CSS

Tags: css, background-image

Is there a way to fake a foreground-image analagous to a background-image in CSS? Instead of existing behind other elements in a div, it would obscure everything inside the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content) (`::before` won't work in [IE≤7](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15)):

```
.obscured{     
    position: relative;
}
.obscured::before{
    position: absolute; /* maximize the pseudo-element */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* use background-image here */
    content: " "; /* it needs actual content, an empty space is enough */
}
```

See also:

- [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsVuX/)
- W3C: [CSS2.1: 12.1 The :before and :after pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#before-after-content)

Answer (score 0):

On way is to use absolute positionning, to cover all the tags. I presume you want to trigger this with an event. So when the event is triggered, you can float all the elements except the foreground

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay a same-size child element with absolute positioning and add a bg image to it.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/hMxxq/) with bg color instead of an image. Tested in FF, Chrome, IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one line of css > `backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);`:

```
<div class="some-background">
  <div style="backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);"></div>
</div>
```